# Resign First Responder not working in only one text field

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfielddelegate

Hopefully somebody can help me out here. I have a UIView with 3 text fields. I want the "return" key from the keyboard to resign the first responder, regardless of which text field the users curser is in. My code works for 2 of the 3 text fields, but consistently (as in always) it refuses to resign first responder from the 3rd text field, and I don't know why (the text fields are identical. The field that does not work is the 3rd field...

Here is the code if it helps

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    [firstTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [secondTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [thirdTextField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

Here is the property declaration in the H

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstTimeTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *secondTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *thirdTextField;
```

It seems pretty straight forward, so I'm wondering if there is some kind of error checking that I should be doing to determine whats happening here.

The file is declared as a UITextFieldDelegate as well...

Thanks for the time and the assistance!

Comment: Have you set the delegate to ALL UITextFields?

Comment: And you don't have to do call resignFirstResponder from all UITextFields. Just use the textField paramenter, the one that actually called the callback. [textField resignFirstResponder].

Comment: Is thirdTextField also hooked up in IB?

Comment: Bone Head move... yes thats right ! I set the 1st two, then came back and added the 3rd but never set the delegate.... Thank you... I'm gonna go facepalm now...

Comment: Natural mistake. I have done that a couple of times thought. Please mark my answer if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set the delegate to ALL UITextFields?

Set the delegate to all UITextFields.